# How can I apply error reporting in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error-log

I googled out how to apply error reporting in Magento 2, but I didn't find any solution yet. It will be useful if there is any link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default Error reporting are possible in frontend using developer
>   mode.

Run command,

Using Developer mode, you can directly check error in frontend browser if any error are occur,

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Changes in file,

Go To **pub** folder of root and rename at below path,

```
pub/erros/local.xml.sample to local.xml
```

Now go to `app/bootstrap.php` file,

Remove # from initial,

**#ini_set('display_errors', 1);**

to

**ini_set('display_errors', 1);**

Comment: How can i mail these errors. Is it possible or not @Rakesh ?

Comment: sorry, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to send exceptions and logs in email while any error triggered in my mageto 2 setup. Can i do this ?

Comment: hm, obviously look in `magento/var/log` no need to mess with ini_set ...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the developer mode on by using following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

It should enable error reporting. When your purpose is done return back to default mode. If you are still not able to find error reporting, then you may add following lines in app/bootstrap.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I would like to mail errors in email. Can i do this ?

Comment: What type of server is your Magento 2 on?  If in Linux I know mine is stored in ```/var/logs/mail.log```    this is in the root of the server, not Magento for me.  You should check which mail service your server is using.  (I use sendmail by default)

Answer (score 0):

In app/bootstrap.php have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

And be in developer mode.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/bootstrap.php

Depending on your server setup apache/nginx/php it would be useful to log all errors to catch Ajax and cron php errors.
All this is for debugging purpose only.

If you're talking about exceptions not being displayed in the page, maybe you have `local.xml` in pub/errors
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/pub/errors